# Find rows that doesn't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables.

Application Table

```
Id: 1, 2, 3
```

User Table

```
Id, 1, 2, 3
```

ApplicationUser Table (A bridge table)

```
AppId   UserId
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       3
```

I need a SQL query to fill up the ApplicationUser table (i.e. the table *should* be)

```
ApplicationUser Table (A bridge table)
AppId   UserId
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
3       3
```

So the query should return `(1, 3) (2, 2) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3)`

Comment: What database are you building query in - Access, SQLServer, MySQL? Add appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross join with exists logic:

```sql
INSERT INTO ApplicationUser (AppId, UserId)
SELECT a.Id, u.Id
FROM Application a
CROSS JOIN User u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ApplicationUser au
                  WHERE au.AppId = a.Id AND au.UserId = u.Id);
```

Comment: @userone . . . Although `EXCEPT` is more elegant, it incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  A `LEFT JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` should have better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Access query, this is a Cartesian association of records.

```
INSERT INTO ApplicationUser(AppID, UserID)
SELECT Application.ID, User.ID
FROM Application, [User];
```

Set the ID fields in ApplicationUser as compound index with NoDuplicates and duplicate pairs will not be allowed.

Comment: SQL Server tagged.

Comment: Yes, just as I posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

When deciding what records to add, use a `CROSS JOIN` to get all the records that *should* and an `EXCEPT` to remove the ones that already do:

```
INSERT ApplicationUser (AppId, UserId)
    SELECT a.Id, u.Id
    FROM Application a CROSS JOIN User u
    EXCEPT
    SELECT AppId, UserId FROM ApplicationUser
;
```